# How to use Naive Bayes in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a text classification model in Tensorflow and want to use the naive bayes classifier but not able to find how to use it.
My algorithm is using tf-idf and naive bayes

Comment: https://nicolovaligi.com/naive-bayes-tensorflow.html

Comment: @Nitesh Singh, You can refer [TensorFlow Naive Bayes Classifier](https://www.kaggle.com/sklasfeld/tensorflow-naive-bayes-classifier) implementation on [Disaster Tweets](https://www.kaggle.com/c/nlp-getting-started). Hope this may helps you. Thanks!